# How to Redirect a subfolder of REACT to main domain?

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

I have a domain (lets say [www.abc123.com](http://www.abc123.com)) and in my cpanel in public html  I have a folder in REACT named as "good". Now I want to redirect it in such a way that when i go to [www.abc123.com](http://www.abc123.com) the contents of folder "good" should come instead of going to www.abc123/good.com.

( [www.abc123.com](http://www.abc123.com) This is only a reference name )

I did try code in .htaccess and it works but partial, as source code in both url is same but the page is not displayed [www.abc123.com](http://www.abc123.com) as it is displayed on www.abc123/good.com

.htacess code was

````
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^$ /good/ [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]
```
`
````